# When is $Z_n[X] / h(X)$ a field?

Tags: field-theory

I'm looking for a neccessary and sufficient condition so that the quotient ring $Z_n[X] / h(X)$ is a field.

Comment: Have you found anything on your own so far? For instance, what can you say about $n$?

Comment: Well, $n$ should be a prime, otherwise a prime divisor $p$ of $n$ won't have an inverse.

Comment: I agree. Note that this means that $\Bbb Z_n$ itself is a field. With that out of the way, we have to focus on $h$. What do you think there?

Comment: I can't think of a proof, but my hunch is that $h(X)$ should be an irreducible in $Z[X]$.

Comment: I think I might have made some mistake with the notation. I meant that the denominator in the quotient is the sub-ring of $Z_n[X]$ that is generated by $h(X)$. Apologies, I (think that I) have a good understanding of group theory, but I am an amateur with rings and fields.

Comment: Yes, $h(X)$ must be irreducible in $\Bbb Z_n[X]$. The reason for this is that $(h(X))$ must be a maximal ideal, which implies that it must be a _prime_ ideal (there are some details in here about unique factorisation that needs to be worked out). Then you also need to prove that this is sufficient.

Comment: If $p$ is prime and $h(X)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ then $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(h(X))$ is a finite integral domain and hence a field.

Comment: Is it possible for $h(X)$ to be irreducible in $Z[X]$ but reducible in $Z_n[X]$?

Answer (score 0):

(collecting the comments into an answer)

- $n$ must be prime, because otherwise there'll be nontrivial zero divisors.
- When $n$ is prime, $\mathbb Z_n$ is a field and so $\mathbb Z_n[X]/(h)(X)$ is a field iff $h(X)$ is irreducible mod $n$.